# Is the C++ NVRO applicable with object slicing or with a local object data member?

Tags: c++, c++17, return-value-optimization

Copy elision starts to become more and more mandatory with each new C++ standard. However, the conditions into which it is applicable are not always obvious and I need help to better understand them to arrange my code in a way that I do take advantage of it.

I was using RVO in the following manner:

```
/*
 * Simplified version of the real thing for the sake of discussion
 */
class Update
{
public:
    Update(double v1, double v2)
    {
        m_values[0] = v1;
        m_values[1] = v2;
    }
private:
  m_values[2];
};

/*
 * handler called during a stream-oriented parsing
 */
class ParserHandler
{
public:
    double getV1() const;
    double getV2() const;
};

Update buildRecord()
{
    ParserHandler handler;

    parse(handler);
    return Update{handler.getV1(), handler.getV2()};
}
```

but I was unsatisfied after the realization that the class ParserHandler was essentially containing a duplicate of the returned update object.

I came with the following. When I wrote it, I was sure that NVRO would kick in but I am not so sure anymore that the standard or my compiler (gcc) will do the optimization:

Idea #1:

```
/*
 * handler called during a stream-oriented parsing
 */
class ParserHandler
{
public:
    Update m_workingUpdate;
};

Update buildRecord()
{
    ParserHandler handler;

    parse(handler);
    return handler.m_workingUpdate;
}
```

Idea #2:

```
/*
 * handler called during a stream-oriented parsing
 */
class ParserHandler : public Update
{
};

Update buildRecord()
{
    ParserHandler handler;

    parse(handler);
    return handler;
}
```

So the question is: will the C++ NVRO kick in in one or both of those 2 setups and if not, what is the best way to minimize copying around the Update return value?

Comment: "*Copy elision starts to become more and more mandatory with each new C++ standard.*" Um, no it doesn't. Only one C++ version made any form of elision mandatory. The most recent version, C++20, changed nothing about it, and nothing on deck for C++23 involves elision either (though there was a proposal for guaranteed NRVO, but it stalled out).

Comment: What's wrong with the original `return Update{handler.getV1(), handler.getV2()};`? You supply the constructor with the arguments it needs. RVO instead of NRVO.

Comment: Nicol, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision RVO has become mandatory in C++17

Comment: Ted, the original issue with using the RVO was that in order for it to work, ParserHandler had to have a copy of the Update guts. IOW, to use RVO, the code had to maintain a copy manually. The initial ParserHandler was equivalent to its definition in idea #1 except that it was not explicit and data members were more or less the copy paste of what was in Update. Also keep in mind that the defs are simplified. There is more copying than 16 bytes in real app

Answer (score 4):

> Idea #1:

Elision in a `return <expr>;` statement only if `<expr>` names a local variable. `handler.m_workingUpdate` names a subobject of a local variable, not a local variable itself. So no elision.

> Idea #2:

Elision in a `return <expr>;` statement only applies if the type of the named local variable exactly matches the return type (minus cv-qualifiers). `handler` is of type `ParserHandler`, which is not the same type as `Update`. So again, no elision.

Comment: in that case, would create a local update object and pass a reference of it to the ParserHandler the best possible option? I guess that at that level, I need to look at the compiler output to make sure that the added level of indirection is not more expensive than the copy...

Comment: @lano1106: "*in that case, would create a local update object and pass a reference of it to the ParserHandler the best possible option?*" I agree with Ted; I don't see the problem with the first code. It's clear and obvious as to what's going on.